# jquery: Removing class transferred from JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel-4

I created a function in laravel that raises some pictures together and returns their names, so I can view them immediately on the page without having to refresh the browser. I want to allow deleting a photo, but it does not give that return values ​​through JSON are not in the DOM. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
  <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="data">
        <input  type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>

<hr>


<div class="returns_img"> </div>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $("form#data").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "upimage",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        async: false,
       success: function(msg){  

        $(".returns_img").append(msg);

   },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

});

   $("#dell_msg").click(function(){

        $(".up_side").removeClass(".list_img");

   });
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::post('upimage', function(){


foreach (Input::file("image") as $image) {

$imagename = time(). $image->getClientOriginalName();


$upload = $image->move(public_path() . "/img/",$imagename);

  if ($upload) {

    $uploaddata [] = $imagename;


  }

  echo "<div class='list_img'><img src='/img/". $imagename. "'><button id='dell_msg'>X</button>    </div>"; 

}
```

Comment: Never used `async: false` it's not recommended.

Comment: I don't see your HTML having the class ".up_side". What element are you trying to target?
Besides, $("#dell_msg").click cannot attach an event handler to an element that doesn't exist yet. You may delegate the handling of this event like so:
$('body').on({click: function(){
  $(".up_side").removeClass(".list_img");
}}, '#dell_msg');

Comment: Or attach the click event after appending the result. Then jQuery can find the element in your document. Just move the .click handling into the success function, right after .append(msg)